# Android - How to set Html text on textview with text include charactor "<" or ">"

Tags: android

When I set html text for textview, but if in text include character "<" or ">" then text view show text is not correct.

For example:

```
mTvMessage.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b> Please help me. <: <b> <br> Can you help me? "));
```

=> The text on text view:

> **Please help me. Can you help me?**

But the text should be:

> **Please help me. <:** 
>   Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`&lt;` for <

`&gt;` for >

`&amp;` for &

Hope it helps!!!